# nginx return 404 if query param contains special char '<'

Tags: nginx

I have url https://myhost.test/en/searchResult?param=<

I want to return 404 if query param have special char '<'

```
https://myhost.test/en/searchResult?param=test ----- Valid url

https://myhost.test/en/searchResult?param=<h1>    ----- return 404
```

I tried below but not working

```
   error_page 420 = @blockUrl;
   location ~ ^/(en)/search {
     if ($args ~* "q=<") {
        return 420;
     }
  }
 location @blockUrl{
    return 404;
 }
```

Could someone please help me how can block having '<' in query param.

Comment: It may be URL encoded. You could try: `if ($args ~* "q=%3C")`

Answer (score 1):

In my tests no matter how I entered the url (encoded or not) it always is encoded in the log file.
Here are two possibilities to accomplish your requirement:

```
if ($args ~* (param=.*(%3C|%3E).*)) {
   return 404;
}
```

or

In your `location` block:

```
if ($err404) {
   return 404;
}
```

In the `http` block (not inside the `server` block!):

```
map $args $err404 {
        ~param=.*(%3C|%3E).*            1;
        default                         0;
}
```